# Meaning of __FILE__ = $0 as given on ruby-lang.org

Tags: ruby

Short Tutorial on Ruby-Lang says the following:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
```

`__FILE__` is the magic variable that contains the name of the current file. `$0` is the name of the file used to start the program. This check says “If this is the main file being used…”

**This allows a file to be used as a library, and not to execute code in that context, but if the file is being used as an executable, then execute that code.**

But the bold lines above are not clear, since I am new to Ruby.

Comment: If you're running the file then run the stuff in the `if` block. If you're `require`ing the file, don't run the code in the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your file is foo.rb, and defines a Foo class. The file can be used in one of two ways.

The first, which you're already familiar with, is to include it in another file or in IRB. It'll go something like:

```
# in otherfile.rb
require 'foo'
foo = Foo.new
```

The `if __FILE__ == $0` line is for the second use case, where you make the file executable and call it directly from the shell. It'll go something like

```
# in the shell
./foo.rb
# alternatively: ruby foo.rb
```

Comment: How will the second use case file will look like? Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: It's just like it says in the answer... Basically, open a Terminal or a DOS window, and execute the script -- like you would list files using `ls` (*nix) or `dir` (DOS). The `./foo.rb` variation assumes you've the appropriate header in the file (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` on *nix) and that the file is executable. The alternative variation (`ruby foo.rb`) does not.

Answer (score 3):

`__FILE__` returns the name of the current file. `$0` returns the name of the script currently being executed.

Imagine you have this file

```
# foo.rb
if __FILE__ == $0
  puts 'foo'
else
  puts 'bar'
end
```

and you run `ruby foo.rb` from the command line then it will output `foo` because both – `__FILE__` and `$0` – return `"foo.rb"`.

But if you have the same `foo.rb` file and require it in another `bar.rb` file like this

```
# bar.rb
require 'foo'
```

and you run the other file `ruby bar.rb` then the script will print `bar` because `__FILE__` would still return `"foo.rb"` but `$0` would now return `"bar.rb"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  #Do something
else
  #Do something else
end
```

This means, the code inside this block will be executed only if you run the file explicitly not if you load it via require or include.

Comment: are you sure you write in Ruby?